# How to calculate the critical chi-square value using Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I know that there's a function called `chi2.isf` in `scipy.stats`. So we can calculate the critical chi-square by calling this function with writing degree of freedom and significance level parameters.

**Example:**

```
from scipy.stats import chi2

print(chi2.isf(df=15, q=0.05))
```

**Output:**

```
24.99579013972863
```

However I want to calculate the critical chi-square value that was described in the below website.

**Source:** https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/formulas.aspx?id=12

While I was trying to convert the formulas into Python codes, I wrote codes like below:

```
from numpy import e, inf
from scipy.integrate import quad


def lower_incomplete_gamma_function(s: float = .0, x: float = .0):
    return quad(lambda t: (t ** (s - 1)) * (e ** (-t)), 0, x)[0]


def gamma_function(z: float = .0):
    return quad(lambda t: (t ** (z - 1)) * (e ** (-t)), 0, inf)[0]
```

What I wonder is, how can I convert the `F(x; k)` into Python codes and then can find the critical chi-square value? What is the step I should follow after the last step? Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that actually this is not a `chi2.isf` code. Referencing the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/discrete.html) of scipy, `isf` is an inverted version of `sf` and can be expressed as `ppf(1-alpha)`, which for it's part is an inverted `cdf` function. `cdf` can be considered as lower gamma, whereas in scipy the lower gamma already contains the division by gamma, so your output looks rather like `cdf` up to 14th digit. 
Hence, in order to compute the critical chi-squared value you should use the inverted lower incomplete gamma function, like that:

`isf = 2 * scipy.special.gammaincinv(k/2, 1-x)`.